# Json deserialization is returning null

Tags: c#, json

I have a big Json file and that I'm trying to deserialize. I used quicktype to write my C# code and these are the classes

```
public partial class GameStats
{
     [JsonProperty("venue")]
     public string Venue { get; set; }

     [JsonProperty("location")]
     public string Location { get; set; }

     [JsonProperty("status")]
     public string Status { get; set; }

     [JsonProperty("time")]
     public string Time { get; set; }

     [JsonProperty("fifa_id")]
     [JsonConverter(typeof(ParseStringConverter))]
     public long FifaId { get; set; }

     [JsonProperty("weather")]
     public Weather Weather { get; set; }

     [JsonProperty("attendance")]
     [JsonConverter(typeof(ParseStringConverter))]
     public long Attendance { get; set; }

     [JsonProperty("officials")]
     public List<string> Officials { get; set; }

     [JsonProperty("stage_name")]
     public string StageName { get; set; }

     [JsonProperty("home_team_country")]
     public string HomeTeamCountry { get; set; }

     [JsonProperty("away_team_country")]
     public string AwayTeamCountry { get; set; }

     [JsonProperty("datetime")]
     public DateTimeOffset Datetime { get; set; }

     [JsonProperty("winner")]
     public string Winner { get; set; }

     [JsonProperty("winner_code")]
     public string WinnerCode { get; set; }

     [JsonProperty("home_team")]
     public Team HomeTeam { get; set; }

     [JsonProperty("away_team")]
     public Team AwayTeam { get; set; }

     [JsonProperty("home_team_events")]
     public List<TeamEvent> HomeTeamEvents { get; set; }

     [JsonProperty("away_team_events")]
     public List<TeamEvent> AwayTeamEvents { get; set; }

     [JsonProperty("home_team_statistics")]
     public TeamStatistics HomeTeamStatistics { get; set; }

     [JsonProperty("away_team_statistics")]
     public TeamStatistics AwayTeamStatistics { get; set; }

     [JsonProperty("last_event_update_at")]
     public DateTimeOffset LastEventUpdateAt { get; set; }

     [JsonProperty("last_score_update_at")]
     public DateTimeOffset LastScoreUpdateAt { get; set; }
}

public partial class Team
{
     [JsonProperty("country")]
     public string Country { get; set; }

     [JsonProperty("code")]
     public string Code { get; set; }

     [JsonProperty("goals")]
     public long Goals { get; set; }

     [JsonProperty("penalties")]
     public long Penalties { get; set; }
}

public partial class TeamEvent
{
     [JsonProperty("id")]
     public long Id { get; set; }
     /*
     [JsonProperty("type_of_event")]
     public TypeOfEvent TypeOfEvent { get; set; }
     */
     [JsonProperty("player")]
     public string Player { get; set; }

     [JsonProperty("time")]
     public string Time { get; set; }
}

public partial class TeamStatistics
{
     [JsonProperty("country")]
     public string Country { get; set; }

     [JsonProperty("attempts_on_goal")]
     public long AttemptsOnGoal { get; set; }

     [JsonProperty("on_target")]
     public long OnTarget { get; set; }

     [JsonProperty("off_target")]
     public long OffTarget { get; set; }

     [JsonProperty("blocked")]
     public long Blocked { get; set; }

     [JsonProperty("woodwork")]
     public long Woodwork { get; set; }

     [JsonProperty("corners")]
     public long Corners { get; set; }

     [JsonProperty("offsides")]
     public long Offsides { get; set; }

     [JsonProperty("ball_possession")]
     public long BallPossession { get; set; }

     [JsonProperty("pass_accuracy")]
     public long PassAccuracy { get; set; }

     [JsonProperty("num_passes")]
     public long NumPasses { get; set; }

     [JsonProperty("passes_completed")]
     public long PassesCompleted { get; set; }

     [JsonProperty("distance_covered")]
     public long DistanceCovered { get; set; }

     [JsonProperty("balls_recovered")]
     public long BallsRecovered { get; set; }

     [JsonProperty("tackles")]
     public long Tackles { get; set; }

     [JsonProperty("clearances")]
     public long Clearances { get; set; }

     [JsonProperty("yellow_cards")]
     public long YellowCards { get; set; }

     [JsonProperty("red_cards")]
     public long RedCards { get; set; }

     [JsonProperty("fouls_committed")]
     public long FoulsCommitted { get; set; }

     [JsonProperty("tactics")]
     public string Tactics { get; set; }

     [JsonProperty("starting_eleven")]
     public List<Player> StartingEleven { get; set; }

     [JsonProperty("substitutes")]
     public List<Player> Substitutes { get; set; }
}

public partial class Player
{
     [JsonProperty("name")]
     public string Name { get; set; }

     [JsonProperty("captain")]
     public bool Captain { get; set; }

     [JsonProperty("shirt_number")]
     public long ShirtNumber { get; set; }

     [JsonProperty("position")]
     public Position Position { get; set; }
}
```

I'm trying to get to players through `TeamStatistics`, but any time I try it `TeamStatistics` is either null or empty.

This is the code that I tried to deserialize it with:

```
RestResponse<TeamStatistics> restResponse = await JsonConversions.GetDataTeamStats(URL_country);

List<TeamStatistics>? dictionary = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<TeamStatistics>(restResponse.Content);
```

or

```
RestResponse<GameStats> restResponse = await JsonConversions.GetDataTeamStats(URL_country);

List<GameStats>? dictionary = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<GameStats>>(restResponse.Content);
```

In the first case every value is null while in the other, only `TeamStatistics` is null().

This is part of the JSON:

```
[
  {
    "venue": "Nizhny Novgorod",
    "location": "Nizhny Novgorod Stadium",
    "status": "completed",
    "time": "full-time",
    "fifa_id": "300331499",
    "weather": {
      "humidity": "36",
      "temp_celsius": "25",
      "temp_farenheit": "57",
      "wind_speed": "9",
      "description": "Partly Cloudy"
    },
    "attendance": "42300",
    "officials": [
      "Joel AGUILAR",
      "Juan ZUMBA",
      "Juan Carlos MORA",
      "Norbert HAUATA",
      "Mauro VIGLIANO",
      "Taleb AL MARRI",
      "Abdulrahman AL JASSIM",
      "Daniele ORSATO",
      "Bertrand BRIAL"
    ],
    "stage_name": "First stage",
    "home_team_country": "Sweden",
    "away_team_country": "Korea Republic",
    "datetime": "2018-06-18T12:00:00Z",
    "winner": "Sweden",
    "winner_code": "SWE",
    "home_team": {
      "country": "Sweden",
      "code": "SWE",
      "goals": 1,
      "penalties": 0
    },
    "away_team": {
      "country": "Korea Republic",
      "code": "KOR",
      "goals": 0,
      "penalties": 0
    },
    "home_team_events": [
      {
        "id": 156,
        "type_of_event": "yellow-card",
        "player": "Viktor CLAESSON",
        "time": "61'"
      },
      {
        "id": 154,
        "type_of_event": "goal-penalty",
        "player": "Andreas GRANQVIST",
        "time": "65'"
      },
      {
        "id": 155,
        "type_of_event": "substitution-out",
        "player": "Albin EKDAL",
        "time": "71'"
      },
      {
        "id": 157,
        "type_of_event": "substitution-in",
        "player": "Oscar HILJEMARK",
        "time": "71'"
      },
      {
        "id": 163,
        "type_of_event": "substitution-out",
        "player": "Ola TOIVONEN",
        "time": "77'"
      },
      {
        "id": 165,
        "type_of_event": "substitution-in",
        "player": "Isaac Kiese THELIN",
        "time": "77'"
      },
      {
        "id": 162,
        "type_of_event": "substitution-out",
        "player": "Sebastian LARSSON",
        "time": "81'"
      },
      {
        "id": 164,
        "type_of_event": "substitution-in",
        "player": "Gustav SVENSSON",
        "time": "81'"
      }
    ],
    "away_team_events": [
      {
        "id": 150,
        "type_of_event": "yellow-card",
        "player": "KIM Shinwook",
        "time": "13'"
      },
      {
        "id": 151,
        "type_of_event": "substitution-out",
        "player": "PARK Jooho",
        "time": "28'"
      },
      {
        "id": 152,
        "type_of_event": "substitution-in",
        "player": "KIM Minwoo",
        "time": "28'"
      },
      {
        "id": 153,
        "type_of_event": "yellow-card",
        "player": "HWANG Heechan",
        "time": "55'"
      },
      {
        "id": 158,
        "type_of_event": "substitution-out",
        "player": "KIM Shinwook",
        "time": "66'"
      },
      {
        "id": 161,
        "type_of_event": "substitution-in",
        "player": "JUNG Wooyoung",
        "time": "66'"
      },
      {
        "id": 159,
        "type_of_event": "substitution-out",
        "player": "KOO Jacheol",
        "time": "73'"
      },
      {
        "id": 160,
        "type_of_event": "substitution-in",
        "player": "LEE Seungwoo",
        "time": "73'"
      }
    ],
    "home_team_statistics": {
      "country": "Sweden",
      "attempts_on_goal": 15,
      "on_target": 4,
      "off_target": 5,
      "blocked": 6,
      "woodwork": 0,
      "corners": 6,
      "offsides": 1,
      "ball_possession": 52,
      "pass_accuracy": 84,
      "num_passes": 417,
      "passes_completed": 352,
      "distance_covered": 102,
      "balls_recovered": 43,
      "tackles": 9,
      "clearances": 30,
      "yellow_cards": 1,
      "red_cards": 0,
      "fouls_committed": 20,
      "tactics": "4-4-2",
      "starting_eleven": [
        {
          "name": "Robin OLSEN",
          "captain": false,
          "shirt_number": 1,
          "position": "Goalie"
        },
        {
          "name": "Mikael LUSTIG",
          "captain": false,
          "shirt_number": 2,
          "position": "Defender"
        },
```

I'm trying to get to that starting eleven.

**Edit**: worldcup-vua.nullbit.hr/men/matches/country?fifa_code=KOR

Comment: Your json is very sloppy. You posted hundrends item in away_team_events array, but nothing in the place you have problems. Cut your json by removing repeating stuff, or better to post the real url

Comment: Sorry first time doing this. (https://worldcup-vua.nullbit.hr/men/matches/country?fifa_code=KOR) is the url. I think that the problem is that all the classes have a List and my deserialization is only accounting for one.

Comment: Do you think we are going to analyze your classes? Without a json string? And where are Position and Weather classes?

Comment: Position is an enum, so is TypeOfEvent. I dont think that the classes are acctualy the issue cause they were run through quicktype.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this works for me ( Since you didn't post  Weather and Position I made them as object, but maybe it is the problem?)

```
List<GameStats> gameStats = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<GameStats>>(json);
```

Comment: Okay, the code was right, me trying to get to the data was wrong. I'm really sorry, this is my first project thats over 2000 lines. I'm being stupid all aroung.